# How to highlight brackets [] and the text within IF it contain specific words or symbol using RegEx?

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex `/\[(.*?)\]/gi` to highlight all texts inside brackets including the brackets.

However, it's giving me a lot of false positives, and I'd like to limit the highlights to brackets that contain specific words and symbols.

Those are: 1. `RSVP` & 2. `§`

So for example, I have the ff:

`[RSVP dog] [§111] [cat]`

It shouldn't target `[cat]` anymore.

How do I go about doing this if it's possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\[[^\]\[]*(?:RSVP|§)[^\]\[]*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WoAcHc/1).

*Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (depending on regex flavor, you might need to use `[^][]*` or `[^\][]*`)
- `(?:RSVP|§)` - `RSVP` or `§`
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (depending on regex flavor, you might need to use `[^][]*` or `[^\][]*`)
- `]` - a `]` char (it must be escaped only in some very few regex flavors, so you might need to use `\]`).

Comment: @ixcode If you precise the regex flavor, I could trim the escaping to the needed minimum.

Comment: Thank you, although this is already enough, I am using it for JavaScript.

Comment: @ixcode Then you need `/\[[^\][]*(?:RSVP|§)[^\][]*]/g`